# Tab Reloader to detect web page update

Tags: web, dynamic, tabs

I'm using [Tab Reloader](https://add0n.com/tab-reloader.html) in Opera to periodically check the website for updates. Currently tabs in Opera reload as they're supposed to. This add-on allows to inject custom code in the web page code so the user could add some functionality.The developer provided example code to check if the web page in reloaded tab had been updated. This code is working, sort of. The problem is it detects the changes in static web pages, but dynamically generated pages can not be detected. The code example below:

```
{
  async function sha256(message) {
    const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode(message);
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', msgBuffer);
    const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer));
    const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => ('00' + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join('');
    return hashHex;
  }
  sha256(document.body.innerText).then(hash => {
    const oh = localStorage.getItem('tab-reloader-hash');
    if (oh && oh !== hash) {
      (new Audio('https://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg')).play()
    }
    localStorage.setItem('tab-reloader-hash', hash);
  });
}
```

The question is how should I modify the code so the add-on will detect the changes in dynamically updated pages. Any suggestions?
Thanks!